# Excel VBA code to index all worksheet names with hyperlinks - in a rectangular shape (button sort of)

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to write a VBA code which will help me index all the worksheet name with hyperlinks. However I do not want just the name of the worksheet written on the cell. I want all the names of the worksheet on a rectangular shape, one below the other. when you click on the shape with the worksheet name on it, it will take you to the worksheet Cell A1. 
Also in other worksheets, a similar rectangular box that says "back to index" which is linked to the index page.

Is there someone who can help me write such a code as i have almost 70 worksheets in a workbook and i am dying trying to do this manually.

below is the specifications of the rectangular box:

```
Sub button()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 96.75, 90, 94.5, 21).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Sheet3"

    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 6). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With

    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 6).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With

    Range("D9").Select
End Sub
```

[image: Image of the look of the buttons, click here]

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cycle for each worksheet taking the names and create the button you want considering the names...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call button(ws)
Next
```

Comment: However I have lots of worksheets, I want a code to do this for me.